# Placing text over an image (have tried other suggestions on here but not working)

Tags: html, css

I am usning PlanetPress Connect and I am trying to place text over an image. I have looked through here and tried some examples but they are not working. The closest I can get is this:

## Investment Returns and Expenses

this places the image on top and the text underneath it. Can someone help me?

Comment: can we get some code too work with?

Comment: I don't think I entered my code in the right way. <--!<div class="image">
    <img src="images/BlueCurve_v2.png" alt="" style="width: 787px; height: 166px;">
    <h1><span style="font-size: 24pt;font-color: #ffffff;">Investment Returns and Expenses</span></h1>
</div>

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749352/vertically-and-horizontally-centering-text-over-an-image?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved many ways the easiest by using position absolute.

```
.image h1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Here is an example - https://jsfiddle.net/ssby4L9c/

Comment: This worked perfect!!!! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

two ways to do it, if you know how you want it i explaine it in more details

```css
.background{
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200');
  margin-bottom:15px;
}

.test2{
  position:relative;
}
img{
   z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}
p{
     z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<div class="background">
you can put the image as background
</div>


<div class="test2">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/cats">
<p>
or you do it this way
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!!!